# How to pass data from an api to another page and receive them to later render on screen?

Tags: flutter

I didn't know how to put a better title to the question..... I have a carousel of images of the rick and morty api, this is the url https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character. I want that when clicking on one of those images it takes me to a page where the rest of the information is shown, here is the model to be more specific.

```
class DataApi {
  String image;
  String name;
  String state;
  String gender;

  DataApi({
    required this.image,
    required this.name,
    required this.state,
    required this.gender,
  });

  factory DataApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataApi(
      image: json['image'],
      name: json['name'],
      state: json['status'],
      gender: json['species'],
    );
    /*name: json["name"],
      state: json["status"],
      gender: json["species"]*/

    //List? get results => null;
  }
}
```

So what I did was wrap the image container with a GestureDetector.

```
return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/details',
              arguments: snapshot.data![index],
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9.0)),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data![index].image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

I don't know if I'm doing it right (or how to do it) because I have to pass the rest of the information as an argument and then receive it in another screen and render it. In this case, they would be inside text widgets

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one of the attributes of the image object is unique, you could pass that forward as part of the URL; then just do a call to get the rest of the information.